# PDF format to screen readers

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, screen-readers

I'm having trouble with PDF and screen readers.

The PDFs are created by Cold Fusion from HTML content.

When we read them with a screen reader it does not stop or pause on end of lines.

It doesn't pause on line breaks, paragraphs, headings, lists, etc. I have to insert a horizontal rule to make it stop.

**For example if I have a structure like this:**

List item 1

List item 2

List item 3

**The screen reader reads:**

List item1List item2List item3

Don't know what to do.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the screen reader software and not your use of ColdFusion to create a PDF.

Comment: This does not happen in all documents. I test with NVDA and the blind testers use JAWS and all see the same error.